# How to convert row count result to another column in Kusto query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I've a table like below and want to add another column which contains the row count of the result.

```
datatable(Name: string, salary: int) 
["a", 500,
"a", 500,
"b", 600, 
"b", 600, 
"c", 800, 
"d", 1900,
"e", 200]
```

Kusto query:

```
datatable
| summarize by Name, Salary
```

My output should be summarized by each Name and also need the total row count of summarize query in separate column. In the above example, after summarize(), I end up getting 5 names by salary. However, having a challenge to get rowcount() in a separate column.

```
Name, Salary, RowCount
"a"      1000      5
"b"      1200      5 
"c"      800      5 
"d"     1900      5
"e"      200      5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try this:

```
let T = datatable(Name: string, salary: int) 
[
    "a", 500,
    "a", 500,
    "b", 600, 
    "b", 600, 
    "c", 800, 
    "d", 1900,
    "e", 200
]
;
let RowCount = toscalar(T | summarize dcount(Name))
;
T
| summarize sum(salary) by Name
| extend RowCount
```

| Name | sum_salary | RowCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1000 | 5 |
| b | 1200 | 5 |
| c | 800 | 5 |
| d | 1900 | 5 |
| e | 200 | 5 |

Comment: I kinda have similar implementation and the query performance goes lower when the record count is very high. I've a table which holds billions of records and here is my current query.


let myQuery = materialized_view('EmployeeSalary')
| where (Name in ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'))
| summarize hint.strategy = shuffle EmployeeSalary=sum(Salary) by Name;
let rowCount = toscalar(query | count);           
myQuery
| extend RecordCount=rowCount
| limit 1000


However, if the MV is executed separately, it results in great performance. When it is used inside the toscalar(), it is timing out.

Comment: Thank you very much!

I was able to achieve with your approach and the performance is great.