# How can I get all but the last row in a KQL query?

Tags: azure, kql, azure-data-explorer

I've got a KQL query, and I want to strip out the last row of data. However, the number of rows returned is variable, so I can't use [`take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/take-operator) (aka `limit`) because I don't know what number to pass it.

Is there any way to get the number of rows returned and pass that to `limit`?

Comment: Can I provide answer using one query?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add in my answer here, you can do probably what you want with [Windows functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/window-functions) and specifically [next()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/next-function).

```
let T = range Timestamp from ago(3h) to ago(1h) step 1m
| extend Value = rand(999);
T
| order by Timestamp asc
| where isnotnull(next(Value)) //If the next value exists it isn't our last record
```

| Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-03-26T04:29:59.9749979Z | 203 |
| 2024-03-26T04:30:59.9749979Z | 866 |
| 2024-03-26T04:31:59.9749979Z | 219 |
| 2024-03-26T04:32:59.9749979Z | 144 |
| 2024-03-26T04:33:59.9749979Z | 350 |
| 2024-03-26T04:34:59.9749979Z | 651 |
| 2024-03-26T04:35:59.9749979Z | 216 |
| 2024-03-26T04:36:59.9749979Z | 390 |
| 2024-03-26T04:37:59.9749979Z | 554 |
| 2024-03-26T04:38:59.9749979Z | 735 |
| 2024-03-26T04:39:59.9749979Z | 799 |
| 2024-03-26T04:40:59.9749979Z | 940 |
| etc | etc |

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any way to do this in one query, but [How to convert row count result to another column in Kusto query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818079/how-to-convert-row-count-result-to-another-column-in-kusto-query) inspired me to do it in two:

```
let result_table = my_table
| query here ...
| order by x // you have to sort to get the same row removed every time!
;
// Now get all but the final row
let num_rows = toscalar(result_table | summarize count());
result_table | take num_rows - 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly my table looks like :

[image]

> How can I get all but the last row in a KQL query?I couldn't find any way to do this in one query

You could do this in one query using below KQL query:

```
RithTest
| extend new_column = 0
| sort by new_column asc
| extend rn=row_number()
| project-away new_column
| order by rn desc
| extend new_column = 0
| sort by new_column asc
| extend rn1=row_number()
| where rn1>1
| order by rn asc
| project-away rn,new_column,rn1
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

[Fiddle.](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA52OMQ%2bCMBCF9/6KixMkmMiqwUF3B%2bNmDCn0IlRozfVINfHHW0IIyOh1evfuva8NMpxrri7oGDJQksMrGoxOskW3BcdUm3ssrgLCrPpTXz9WySAPVmstR3WsLHdB3MROjJ3iA/hiNAoM%2bry0TdeawNmEvbPEULznhnTlFCCTkfW56doCKYqD8SSrseS19HIeC44lhdSXkQGF85Y/sOmS6ysk7I19umANyZ9/kUmm6iSEvihhu7FjAQAA)